# Javascript Function Scope vs Object Scope

Tags: javascript, scope

I've gotten to the point where I am trying to fill out my javascript knowledge with some of the more advaned concepts.

I think I a pretty much understand how scope works.  Where objects inherit from a prototype and then global scope, while functions offer a more traditional block scope within themselves.

What I am have trouble understanding is this:

```
function a(){
  console.log(this.z);
  }

a.z = 12;

a(); //returns undefined :(
```

I was expecting to echo out 12, but of course, it doesn't.  Where exactly is z being stored?  what does "this" refer to in the example?

Comment: A(); will ignore the z to be set. You can do: a = new a(); and a.z = 12;

Comment: `this` does *not* (usually) refer to the function-object (and is *not* related to the scope of the function at all!); rather, it refers to the "context" of the function

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/javascript-this-keyword

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call a function, JavaScript will set the current context (`this`) as the object on which it is called. If the function is not attached to any object, by default global object (`window` object in browsers) will be used <sup>*</sup>.

So, in this case, `this` refers to the global object, not `a`. In the global object, `z` hasn't been defined yet. That is why it returns `undefined`.

To get the value 12, you need to access it like this

```
function a() {
    console.log(a.z);   // Use `a` itself, instead of `this`.
}

a.z = 12;

a();
```

<sup>* In strict mode, `this` will be set to `undefined`, if the function is called without any explicit object reference.</sup>

Comment: Light bulb went off.  A lot of code patterns I have been seeing make sense now.  Thank you